# interacting through svg-mask not possible

Tags: html, css, svg, z-index, mask

I want to cover my whole website despite a small circle that follows the cursor. So I made a svg with a circle-mask that updates it's position via jquery. But now all my elements below are not clickable, because the svg lays in front of them. Is there a solution how to solve this?

```
<svg viewbox="0 0 100 50" width="500%" height="500%" id="mouseoverlay" class="mouseoverlay" style="position:fixed;">
<defs>
    <filter id="gauss">
        <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="0.4"/>
    </filter>
    <mask id="mask" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="30">
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" fill="#fff"/>
     <circle cx="50" cy="25" r="4.5" filter="url(#gauss)" />
    </mask>
</defs>
<rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" mask="url(#mask)" fill="#bbb" fill-opacity="1"/>
```

```
$(document).mousemove(function (e) {
        var bodyOffsets = document.body.getBoundingClientRect();
        var fensterhoehe = window.innerHeight;
        var fensterbreite = window.innerWidth;
        tempX = e.pageX - (fensterbreite*2.5);
        tempY = e.pageY - (fensterhoehe*2.5);
        $('#mouseoverlay').css({'top':(tempY - scrollY),'left':tempX}).fadeIn("3000");
}
```

[circle mask](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DjSJD.jpg)

Comment: Please use the fiddle for your code?

Comment: You can use pointer-events : ex: `#mouseoverlay {pointer-events:none;}`. It won't catch the mouse anymore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take a look at [`pointer-events`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events).

ex

```js
var tempX;
var tempY;

$(document).mousemove(function (e) {

        var bodyOffsets = document.body.getBoundingClientRect();
        var fensterhoehe = window.innerHeight;
        var fensterbreite = window.innerWidth;
        tempX = e.pageX - (fensterbreite*2.5);
        tempY = e.pageY - (fensterhoehe*2.5);
        $('#mouseoverlay').css({'top':(tempY - scrollY),'left':tempX}).fadeIn("3000");
});
```

```css
#mouseoverlay {pointer-events:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>HTML Ipsum Presents</h1>

<p><strong>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique</strong> senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. <em>Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.</em> Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, <code>commodo vitae</code>, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. <a href="#">Donec non enim</a> in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis.</p>

<h2>Header Level 2</h2>

<ol>
   <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
   <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
</ol>

<blockquote><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus magna. Cras in mi at felis aliquet congue. Ut a est eget ligula molestie gravida. Curabitur massa. Donec eleifend, libero at sagittis mollis, tellus est malesuada tellus, at luctus turpis elit sit amet quam. Vivamus pretium ornare est.</p></blockquote>

<h3>Header Level 3</h3>

<ul>
   <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
   <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
</ul>

<pre><code>
#header h1 a {
  display: block;
  width: 300px;
  height: 80px;
}
</code></pre>
<h1>HTML Ipsum Presents</h1>

<p><strong>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique</strong> senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. <em>Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.</em> Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, <code>commodo vitae</code>, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. <a href="#">Donec non enim</a> in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis.</p>

<h2>Header Level 2</h2>

<ol>
   <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
   <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
</ol>

<blockquote><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus magna. Cras in mi at felis aliquet congue. Ut a est eget ligula molestie gravida. Curabitur massa. Donec eleifend, libero at sagittis mollis, tellus est malesuada tellus, at luctus turpis elit sit amet quam. Vivamus pretium ornare est.</p></blockquote>

<h3>Header Level 3</h3>

<ul>
   <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
   <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
</ul>

<pre><code>
#header h1 a {
  display: block;
  width: 300px;
  height: 80px;
}
</code></pre>
<h1>HTML Ipsum Presents</h1>

<p><strong>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique</strong> senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. <em>Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.</em> Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, <code>commodo vitae</code>, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. <a href="#">Donec non enim</a> in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis.</p>

<h2>Header Level 2</h2>

<ol>
   <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
   <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
</ol>

<blockquote><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus magna. Cras in mi at felis aliquet congue. Ut a est eget ligula molestie gravida. Curabitur massa. Donec eleifend, libero at sagittis mollis, tellus est malesuada tellus, at luctus turpis elit sit amet quam. Vivamus pretium ornare est.</p></blockquote>

<h3>Header Level 3</h3>

<ul>
   <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
   <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
</ul>

<pre><code>
#header h1 a {
  display: block;
  width: 300px;
  height: 80px;
}
</code></pre>
<h1>HTML Ipsum Presents</h1>

<p><strong>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique</strong> senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. <em>Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.</em> Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, <code>commodo vitae</code>, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. <a href="#">Donec non enim</a> in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis.</p>

<h2>Header Level 2</h2>

<ol>
   <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
   <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
</ol>

<blockquote><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus magna. Cras in mi at felis aliquet congue. Ut a est eget ligula molestie gravida. Curabitur massa. Donec eleifend, libero at sagittis mollis, tellus est malesuada tellus, at luctus turpis elit sit amet quam. Vivamus pretium ornare est.</p></blockquote>

<h3>Header Level 3</h3>

<ul>
   <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
   <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
</ul>

<pre><code>
#header h1 a {
  display: block;
  width: 300px;
  height: 80px;
}
</code></pre>











<svg viewbox="0 0 100 50" width="500%" height="500%" id="mouseoverlay" class="mouseoverlay" style="position:fixed;">
<defs>
    <filter id="gauss">
        <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="0.4"/>
    </filter>
    <mask id="mask" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="30">
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" fill="#fff"/>
     <circle cx="50" cy="25" r="4.5" filter="url(#gauss)" />
    </mask>
</defs>
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" mask="url(#mask)" fill="#bbb" fill-opacity="1"/>  </svg>
```